# Scoped find_or_create_by returning Nil instead of creating record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Instead of creating the record, `find_or_create_by` is just returning `nil`. And I'm not sure why.

I'm doing this:

```
current_store.jet.find_or_create_by(seller_id: seller_id) do |credentials|
  credentials.update_attributes(
  marketplace: marketplace,
  seller_id: seller_id,
  auth_token: auth_token)
end
```

And it returns this, instead of creating the record for some reason:

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `find_or_create_by' for nil:NilClass
```

I've checked all the arguments and they are correct. But sure there is no `jet` instance yet, but that's the point.

My Jet table looks like this:

```
create_table "jets", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text "auth_token"
  t.text "marketplace"
  t.integer "store_id"
  t.boolean "three_speed"
  t.text "seller_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

And my `current_store` method looks like this, and is returning the correct store.

```
def current_store
  @current_store ||= Store.find(session[:fba_shipping_id])
end
```

Where did I go astray?

EDIT:
Here is some more info on the relationships..

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :jet
end
```

And

```
class Jet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end
```

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing the association definitions between `Store` and `Jet`, but if `Store` `has_many :jets` , then shouldn't you have a pluralized `jets` in your statement?  (e.g. `current_store.jets.find_or_create_by` )

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra good idea, and I updated the OP, but `Store` `has_one` `Jet` and `Jet` `belongs_to` `Store`

Comment: Ah, on a `has_one` the syntax is a little different.  You have to use the `build_other` method.  Try `current_store.build_jet.find_or_create_by` ...

Comment: Shoot.. that returned `NoMethodError (undefined method `find_or_create_by' for #<Jet:0x007f4a6ca87808>):`

Comment: when I did this `current_store.build_jet.find_or_create_by(seller_id: seller_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current issue is that

```
current_store.jet
```

returns `nil` thus the `NoMethodError`.

If a store only has 1 `Jet` then the `Store` can also only have 1 `Seller` of that 1 `Jet`.

`has_one` ([Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one)) offers the builder methods `build_association` and `create_association` so you could go with

```
current_store.create_jet(marketplace: marketplace,
  seller_id: seller_id,
  auth_token: auth_token)
```

However you may want to make sure that the `Store` does not already have a `Jet` such as

```
@jet = current_store.jet || current_store.create_jet(marketplace: marketplace,
                              seller_id: seller_id,
                              auth_token: auth_token)
```

This will not update an existing `Jet` if that was your intention as pointed out by @HeliosdeGuerra in the comments. If you truely wanted to use these methods and update an existing `Jet` you could go with something obtuse like:

```
@jet = current_store.jet || current_store.create_jet(seller_id: seller_id)
@jet.update_attributes(marketplace: marketplace,auth_token: auth_token)
```

However in both instances you should ensure the `Jet` has passed validation e.g.

```
# Example 1
  @jet = current_store.jet || current_store.create_jet(marketplace: marketplace,
                              seller_id: seller_id,
                              auth_token: auth_token)
  if @jet.persisted? 
    # passed validation or already existed
  else
    # failed validation
  end 

# Example 2 
  @jet = current_store.jet || current_store.create_jet(seller_id: seller_id)
  if @jet.update_attributes(marketplace: marketplace,auth_token: auth_token)
     # passed validation
  else
     # failed validation
  end
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this would not update the attributes of an existing `jet` ...  Its not clear whether @ToddT wants to update those attributes if a jet already exists or not.  Judging by the fields, it seems he probably wouldn't want to update those fields, but the way he originally wrote the method I assumed he did want to update the fields.

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra updated and honestly I would use your solution excepting the fact that I am not sure what would happen if the `store_id` existed but the `seller_id` did not as this would create 2 `Jet`s for 1 `Store`. I assume this would orphan the newly created `Jet` due to a limit 1 on the query for `has_one`

Comment: Ah, good point... I'll update my answer to better account for that situation, as an alternative to the good solutions you are providing...

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a `has_one` association, it would probably be clearer to write the method as follows:

```
Jet.find_or_create_by(store_id: current_store.id) do |jet|
  jet.seller_id = seller_id
  jet.marketplace = marketplace
  jet.auth_token = auth_token
end
```

It seems to me, this would accomplish what you're looking to do, but in a more standard way.

Keep in mind, that this will not update the attributes(`seller_id`, `marketplace`, `auth_token`) of an existing `jet` but would create one with those attributes if the `current_store` does not already have a `jet` assigned.

Are you wanting to update those attributes even if a record already exists?

[Rails Documentation: find_or_create_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by)